# How to use libuv for direct file descriptor reads?

Tags: libuv

As part of an investigation for a project I am working on, I've been looking into different event loop mechanisms/libraries to use for detection and reading of data from sockets.  Specifically, what I need to do is simple:

1. Detect data from client connections
2. Pass the file descriptor to worker threads to read and process

Epoll edge triggering worked great for this purpose, and I like the edge triggered behavior so I only get notified once when data is available.  I tried implementing using libev doing something like the below pseudo code and this appears to work:

```
void read_cb(struct ev_loop *loop, struct ev_io *watcher, int revents) {
    1. Check for errors
    2. ev_io_stop(loop, watcher) so I don't get constantly notified
    3. Assign the ev_io watcher pointer into worker thread accessible data structure
    3. Signal worker thread
    4. Worker thread begins reading from watcher->fd
    5. When worker thread get EAGAIN, start the watcher again
```

Since `libuv` is intended for similar purpose and is edge triggered, I am trying to do something similar but haven't been successful yet.  With `libuv`, I understand that you can `use uv_read_start` for reading data from streams, but with this method, the `uv_read_cb` returns a buffer filled with the data.  As I need to manipulate that amount of data that needs to be read, and to avoid extra copy of the data from this buffer to a different structure, I'd like to be able to read directly from the socket.

Is this scenario something that `libuv` can be used for?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This commit adds the possibility to get the file descriptor of an underlying stream: https://github.com/joyent/libuv/commit/4ca9a363897cfa60f4e2229e4f15ac5abd7fd103

You can use:

```c
int uv_fileno(const uv_handle_t* handle, uv_os_fd_t* fd);
```

Then read from the FD however you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to find an example that does what I describe in my previous post.  For those who'd be interested on how this is done, here is [the link](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/TYPESTER/UV-0.2/deps/libuv/test/test-poll.c).

Testing this had yielded additional questions but I'll post those separately as they are related more to edge/level trigger behaviour rather than the library.